# Runge–Kutta fourth-order method

Tags: python, numerical-methods, runge-kutta

I'm implementing Runge–Kutta fourth-order method for system of two equations.

[image]

h is number of segments, so T/h is step.

```
def cauchy(f1, f2, x10, x20, T, h):
    x1 = [x10]
    x2 = [x20]

    for i in range(1, h):
        k11 = f1((i-1)*T/h, x1[-1], x2[-1])
        k12 = f2((i-1)*T/h, x1[-1], x2[-1])
        k21 = f1((i-1)*T/h + T/h/2, x1[-1] + T/h/2*k11, x2[-1] + T/h/2*k12)
        k22 = f2((i-1)*T/h + T/h/2, x1[-1] + T/h/2*k11, x2[-1] + T/h/2*k12)
        k31 = f1((i-1)*T/h + T/h/2, x1[-1] + T/h/2*k21, x2[-1] + T/h/2*k22)
        k32 = f2((i-1)*T/h + T/h/2, x1[-1] + T/h/2*k21, x2[-1] + T/h/2*k22)
        k41 = f1((i-1)*T/h + T/h, x1[-1] + T/h*k31, x2[-1] + T/h*k32)
        k42 = f2((i-1)*T/h + T/h, x1[-1] + T/h*k31, x2[-1] + T/h*k32)

        x1.append(x1[-1] + T/h/6*(k11 + 2*k21 + 2*k31 + k41))
        x2.append(x2[-1] + T/h/6*(k12 + 2*k22 + 2*k32 + k42))

    return x1, x2
```

Then I'm testing it on this system:

[image]

```
def f1(t, x1, x2):
    return x2

def f2(t, x1, x2):
    return -x1

def true_x1(t):
    return np.cos(t) + np.sin(t)

def true_x2(t):
    return np.cos(t) - np.sin(t)
```

It seems to be working fine (I also tested it with different initial values and different functions: all works fine):

```
x10 = 1
x20 = 1
T = 1
h = 10

x1, x2 = cauchy(f1, f2, x10, x20, T, h)
t = np.linspace(0, T, h)

plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('x1')
plt.plot(t, true_x1(t), "blue", label="true_x1")
plt.plot(t, x1, "red", label="approximation_x1")
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.97, 0.27))
plt.show()

plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('x2')
plt.plot(t, true_x2(t), "blue", label="true_x2")
plt.plot(t, x2, "red", label="approximation_x2")
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.97, 0.97))
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Then I want to check if the error is on the order of `O(step^4)`, so I reduce step and compute error like this:

[image]

```
step = []
x1_error = []
x2_error = []
for segm in reversed(range(10, 1000)):
    x1, x2 = cauchy(f1, f2, x10, x20, T, segm)
    t = np.linspace(0, T, segm)
    step.append(1/segm)
    x1_error.append(np.linalg.norm(x1 - true_x1(t), np.inf))
    x2_error.append(np.linalg.norm(x2 - true_x2(t), np.inf))
```

And I get this:

```
plt.plot(step, x1_error, label="x1_error")
plt.plot(step, x2_error, label="x2_error")
plt.legend()
```

[image]

So, the error is linear from step. This is really strange, because it is supposed to be on the order of `O(step^4)`. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(1, h):
```

This will iterate from `1` to `h-1`. As the last step is missing, the difference from `x[h-1]` at time `T-T/h` to the exact solution at time `T` is `O(T/h)`.

Thus use

```
for i in range(1,h+1):
```

for `h` steps from `i-1` to `i` or

```
for i in range(h):
```

for `h` steps from `i` to `i+1`.

---

Also, `np.linspace(0,1,4)` will produce `4` equally spaced numbers where the first is `0` and the last is `1`, resulting in

```
array([ 0.        ,  0.33333333,  0.66666667,  1.        ])
```

which is probably not what you were expecting. Thus with the above correction use

```
t = np.linspace(0, T, segm+1)
```

to use the same time points in both computations.

---

It would be easier to follow your code if you would use the letters in their usual meaning, where `h` or `dt` is the step size and `N` is the number of steps. Then define before the loop `h=T/N` or `dt=T/N` to avoid the repeated use of `T/N` in the function calls.